Dyadic Partition of Unity Argument for Estimating the Central Values of L-functions
I've often see it said in many papers that one can obtain an estimate for an $L$-series $L(s,f) = \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{a_{f}(n)}{n^{s}}$ (for simplicity assume $L(s,f)$ is entire) at $s = \frac{1}{2}$ by using a smooth dyadic partition of unity to deduce that
$$L\left(\frac{1}{2},f\right) \ll \frac{1}{\sqrt{q(f))}}\max_{X \ll q(f)^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}}A_{\psi}(X),$$
where $\psi$ is a bump function with compact support on $[1,2]$ and
$$A_{\psi}(X) = \sum_{n \ge 1}a_{f}(n)\psi\left(\frac{n}{X}\right).$$
I've never seen a proof of this fact, and I tried to write one down myself, but I am stuck. I first applied the approximate functional equation in the form
$$L\left(\frac{1}{2},f\right) = \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{a_{f}(n)}{\sqrt{n}}V_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{q(f)}}\right)+\epsilon(f)\frac{\overline{a_{f}}(n)}{\sqrt{n}}V_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{q(f)}}\right).$$
This formula implies the bound
$$L\left(\frac{1}{2},f\right) \ll \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{a_{f}(n)}{\sqrt{n}}V_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{q(f)}}\right)$$
It now seems that the dyadic partition of unity $\left\{\psi\left(\frac{x}{2^{k}}\right)\sigma(x)^{-1}\right\}_{k \ge 0}$ should be used to localize the sum to $n \ll \sqrt{q(f)}$. Here $\sigma(x) = \sum_{k \ge 0}\psi\left(\frac{x}{2^{k}}\right)$. But as it stands, this is not a partition of unity since it vanishes at $x = 2^{k}$. Do we actually need different bump functions and the literature is lazy in this respect? How is the partition of unity being applied? I would appreciate a rigorous explanation if possible.
